# Inner $.getJSON won't go to second element in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

`array1` is `["orange","blue"]`.

```
$.getJSON("path1.json",function(array1){
    for (var i = array1.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var path2 = array1[i];
        console.log(path2);
        $.getJSON(path2,function(someObject){
            console.log("Inside the second $.getJSON function");
            console.log(path2);
        });
    }
});
```

The output looks like this.

```
"orange"
"blue"
"Inside the second $.getJSON function"
"blue"
"Inside the second $.getJSON function"
"blue"
```

Why isn't the output this?

```
"orange"
"Inside the second $.getJSON function"
"orange"
"blue"
"Inside the second $.getJSON function"
"blue"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things going on:

- `$.getJSON()` is partially asynchronous. The implication of this is that your callbacks happen asynchronously.
- Variables declared with `var` are scoped to the function, not the block, and, while you can re-declare a variable in a given scope using `var`, doing so has no effect.

When you combine these things, you end up with a situation where all iterations of the `for` loop are completed before any of the callbacks are called and so, by the time a callback happens, `path2` has been updated several times. (Coincidentally, this doesn't actually effect the inner `$.getJSON()` call itself since `path2` is passed in by value.)

In the old days, we'd have to fix the scope of the value of `path2` (usually via an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)) so it doesn't get overwritten before the callback is executed:

```
$.getJSON("path1.json", function(array1){
    for (var i = array1.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var path2 = array1[i];
        console.log(path2);
        $.getJSON(path2,
            function(path2) {
                return function(someObject){
                    console.log("Inside the second $.getJSON function");
                    console.log(path2);
                };
            }(path2)
        );
    }
});
```

These days, we have `let`, which scopes variables to the block. `for`'s block scope is created new on each iteration and that scope instance is bound to the callback each time the callback function is created, so the following works:

```
$.getJSON("path1.json",function(array1){
    for (var i = array1.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        let path2 = array1[i];
        console.log(path2);
        $.getJSON(path2, function(someObject){
            console.log("Inside the second $.getJSON function");
            console.log(path2);
        });
    }
});
```